# Defining different schema for both get and post request - AutoSchema Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I am trying to define AutoSchema (to be shown in django rest framework swagger) for my REST API in Django REST framework. There's this class that extends APIView.

The class has both 'get' and 'post' methods. Like:

```
class Profile(APIView):
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
schema = AutoSchema(
    manual_fields=[
        coreapi.Field("username",
                      required=True,
                      location='query',
                      description='Username of the user'),

    ]
)
def get(self, request):
    return
schema = AutoSchema(
    manual_fields=[
        coreapi.Field("username",
                      required=True,
                      location='form',
                      description='Username of the user '),
        coreapi.Field("bio",
                      required=True,
                      location='form',
                      description='Bio of the user'),

    ]
)
def post(self, request):
    return
```

The problem is I want different schema for both get and post request. How can I achieve this using AutoSchema?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can **create custom Schema** and override [get_manual_fields](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/7c3477dcdae558b40acfa116ed08eeb5700818eb/rest_framework/schemas/coreapi.py#L529) method to provide custom `manual_fields` list based on the method:

```
class CustomProfileSchema(AutoSchema):
    manual_fields = []  # common fields

    def get_manual_fields(self, path, method):
        custom_fields = []
        if method.lower() == "get":
            custom_fields = [
                coreapi.Field(
                    "username",
                    required=True,
                    location='form',
                    description='Username of the user '
                ),
                coreapi.Field(
                    "bio",
                    required=True,
                    location='form',
                    description='Bio of the user'
                ),
            ]
        if method.lower() == "post":
            custom_fields = [
                coreapi.Field(
                    "username",
                    required=True,
                    location='query',
                    description='Username of the user'
                ),
            ]
        return self._manual_fields + custom_fields


class Profile(APIView):
    schema = CustomProfileSchema()
    ...
```

Comment: Should be 
`manual_fields = super().get_manual_fields(path, method)`

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what is your problem correctly, you can define your schema in each method like this:

```
class Profile(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
         # your logic
         self.schema = AutoSchema(...) # your 'get' schema
         return

    def post(self, request):
        self.schema = AutoSchema(...) # your 'post' schema
        return
```